# Getting error 400 when sending image to AWS S3 in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-s3

I have a flutter app and i'm trying to send a image to my amazon aws bucket. The problem is the statuscode of the post is 400 and i dont know why. Next i'm showing the parameters i'm passing to the uploadFile function:

```dart
await AwsS3.uploadFile(
   accessKey: "myAccessKey",
   secretKey: "mySecretKey",
   file: File(imagePath!),
   bucket: "nameOfMyBucket",
   region: "sa-east-1",
);
```

What can I do?

I tried printing the variables inside the aws package and all seems to be right

**UPDATE**

```dart
print("response.request ${response.request}");
print("response.headers ${response.headers}");
print("response.statusCode ${response.statusCode}");

I/flutter ( 6778): response.request POST https://myBucket.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/
I/flutter ( 6778): response.headers {connection: close, transfer-encoding: chunked, date: Thu, 11 Jan 2024 13:43:08 GMT, x-amz-request-id: ID, content-type: application/xml, x-amz-id-2: ANOTHERID/ID, server: AmazonS3}
I/flutter ( 6778): response.statusCode 400
```

Comment: There are a [lot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) of possible causes for a 400 response. It would be helpful to see more details of the response e.g. network capture or debug logging.

Comment: Take a look at my update, please